# change the title of default Copy in UIMenuController

Tags: ios, iphone, uimenucontroller

In the `UIMenuController` there is a default `Copy` action, I want to change its title to be in another language (Arabic Language).

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you.

https://github.com/questbeat/QBPopupMenu

https://github.com/cxa/UIMenuItem-CXAImageSuppor

[How could I replace UIMenuController with my own view when text is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595587/how-could-i-replace-uimenucontroller-with-my-own-view-when-text-is-selected)